# Spring MVC + AJAX Call Not Returning in JQuery Script

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement a very basic AJAX call in my Spring application (Never used AJAX before). For now I'm just trying to make a call that returns a string, and updates a text area in a form. I know the JQuery code is getting invoked no issues as I can debug the sending part in my browser, and the controller is getting the request. I thought the @ResponseBody annotation was somehow supposed to magically return just the contents of the method return value but its like JQuery doesn't "see" it or something. The controller simply returns the string back and the entire html page just shows the string. I cannot hit the SUCCESS portion in debug in the JQuery call. Am I missing something here?

**Form (truncated for readability)**

```
<form id="ajaxTaskUpdate" th:action="@{/updateTask}" th:object="${Task}" method="post"> 
     <textarea id="taskDescription" name="taskDescription" class="materialize-textarea blue" th:text="${task.description}" maxlength="250"></textarea>
</form>
```

**Jquery snippet**

```
$('#ajaxTaskUpdate').submit(function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url : $("#ajaxTaskUpdate").attr("action"),
                data : data,
                type : "POST",
                success : function(response) {
                    //BREAKPOINT NEVER HITS HERE
                    $("#taskDescription").text(response);
                },
                error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

            return false;
});
```

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateTask",  produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public  String updateTask(Task task) {
    //I want this to be "ajaxed" into my form's text area
    return "successful Ajax Response!";
}
```

**GUI after Controller response**

[image]

Comment: Did your ajax call successfully requested to the server? Coz i dont think so

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is, unless the form itself is somehow hitting it or something. I can debug through the Ajax call on the html side, and immediatley after the .ajax line it hits a breakpoint in my controller.

Comment: I think you are actually requesting post by submitting the form to the server. Though the page is refreshed so your ajax request can't get executed. I have to remain to the page to execute any javascript method or event.

Comment: It's fine. You return just string from the controller and the string is shown. Try to return a POJO with fields and see the results. To check JS call set breakpoints to success and error methods and check one of them is hit

Comment: I believe Zico was on the right track with this one. To sum up exactly what was happening, I was able to debug from the ajax snippet on my client side (html) and it was sending correctly to the server (spring mvc controller). When the controller returned the string it was causing the web browser to refresh, I guess this is default form behavior. I updated my JQuery to include event.preventDefault(); before making the .ajax call and it seems to do the trick. @Zico if you wanna post an actual answer I will gladly accept it to give you credit. Thanks.

Comment: @Jason okay. i have wrote an answer with details for you. Hopefully this might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually requesting post by submitting the form to the server. Though the page is refreshed so your ajax request can't get executed. I have to remain to the page to execute any javascript method or event.

1. You have stop the form submission from html submit button to execute ajax request
2. Fix the url of ajax like `/updateTask` or wherever you want
3. Set dataType as `json` in ajax
4. Took `Task` as `@RequestBody` in controller
5. Make the controller `consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`
6. Make the `data` json string in ajax parameter